# Input parameter change as loop calls for another def (python 3.0), why?

Tags: python, list, loops

I can just not figure out why my input parameter(board) is changing in the loop..

The def iterate takes in the list "board" from def initiate. And it should do this once, and I checked, it is only calling def initiate once. The problem occurs in the loop "for i in range(0,size()):" in def iterate. Here, the list "old_board" somehow changes. If I have 5 rounds and 5 lists in the list "old_board", the second round changes the values of old_board[1] and so on.. Why is this happening? And how can I solve it?

(Parameter list and list in the loop should be equal)

This is the output:

"This is the parameter list  : [[1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

This is the list in the loop: [[1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

This is the list in the loop: [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

This is the list in the loop: [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

This is the list in the loop: [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

This is the list in the loop: [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]"

This is the code:

```
def iterate(board):
    old_board = board
    print('This is the parameter list  :',old_board)
    new_board = board                                       
    living = 0                                                  # Value of alive cells in the future new board

    for i in range(0,size()):                                # Nestled loop that iterate through the old board
        print('This is the list in the loop:',old_board)
        for j in range(0,size()):                            # and sets new values depending on the status of each old cell
            new_value = living_neighbors(i,j,old_board)[1]
            new_board[i][j] = new_value
            living += new_value
    print(new_board)
    print(living) 

    return (living, new_board)
iterate(initiate()[0])
```

Comment: old_board = board = new_board etc makes all these variable point to the same list. When you edit that list you will edit them all. If you write something like old_board = board[:] instead this should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing this

```
old_board = board
new_board = board
```

You don't create new objects but merely new references to the existing ones. 
You can use the copy module or the syntax suggested by Alex to create new objects.

```
from copy import deepcopy
old_board = deepcopy(board)
```

Here you can find a detailed explanation:
http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php

Answer (score 1):

Here, you don't copy your list, you just make a new link to existing list

```
old_board = board
print('This is the parameter list  :',old_board)
new_board = board
```

If you need a copy of it, you should do it like this:

```
old_board = board[:]
print('This is the parameter list  :',old_board)
new_board = board[:]
```

see [FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It got me into understanding the problem.